# How to call a named function from onPressed method of ElevatedButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This works:

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () => {
             setState(() {
               userInputTextControllers.removeAt(index);
               userTextList.removeAt(index);
             })
    }, 
    child: const Text("R"))
 )
```

This doesn't:

```
ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: f(index),
        
        child: const Text("R"))
     )

f(int index) {
   setState(() {
        userInputTextControllers.removeAt(index);
        userTextList.removeAt(index);
   })
}
```

Here, `index` comes from ListView.

In the 2nd code, it throws error saying `setState can't be called during build`.

Why is that so and what can be done to put the code in a separate named function with `index` parameter?

Comment: `f` would need to return a function for your second example to work (ie the function to be executed on press).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, `onPressed` parameter takes function without parameters, but your **f** function takes an int.

So, if you want to call it directly, try that code:

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed:()=>f(index),
    ...
),
```

Answer (score 1):

For extra clarity to freaklessgamer's very good answer:

If your function `f` did not take any parameters, you could simply pass the name of the function in:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: f,
  ...
),
```

Because `f` needs that parameter (as written), you'll have to instead wrap the call in an anonymous function as pointed out before:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () =>f(index),
  ...
),
```